# Android + java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When compiling my code i get this error ("java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method") and I still can't figure why.

Here is my code:

```
    public class FragmentDetails extends Fragment {

        private TextView text1, text2, text3, text4, text5 = null;
        private Button button1 = null;


        OnDetailsDefinedListener mCallback;

        public interface OnDetailsDefinedListener {
            void executeOrder(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e);
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

            button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(...);

            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                text1 = getActivity().findViewById(...);
                text2 = getActivity().findViewById(...);
                text3 = getActivity().findViewById(...);
                text4 = getActivity().findViewById(...);
                text5 = getActivity().findViewById(...);

                String a = text1.getText().toString();
                String b = text2.getText().toString();
                String c= text3.getText().toString();
                String d= text4.getText().toString();
                String e= text5.getText().toString();

                //this is where my error appears
                mCallback.executeOrder(a, b, c, d, e);
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

(here is my error message)

```
    05-26 09:39:20.868    2916-2916/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.blueHatCoder.myapplication, PID: 2916
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.blueHatCoder.myapplication.FragmentDetails$OnDetailsDefinedListener.executeOrder(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.blueHatCoder.myapplication.FragmentDetails$6.onClick(FragmentDetails.java:131)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: mCallback is never initiated...

Answer (score 5):

`mCallback` is never initiated.
you have to do something like that:

```
mCallback = new OnDetailsDefinedListenerImpl(); 
mCallback.executeOrder(a, b, c, d, e);
```

or

```
mCallback = new OnDetailsDefinedListener(){
   @Override
   void executeOrder(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e){
     //doSomething
   };
}
```

Comment: the thing is...since i'm using an interface, the purpose is for the activity who implements it to have the code that "do something". Another thing is that i did exactly the same on another fragment (didn't initialized the mCallback) and it worked...

Comment: no. if something is never initiated you will get a NPE. Always!

Comment: you're right...my mistake and i just found what i was missing. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @BlueHatCoder What were you missing? I'm having the same problem and cannot see why mCallback needs to be initialized.

Comment: @StefanBeike I cannot initialize mCallback = new OnDetailsDefinedListenerImpl(). I get the issue: OnDetailsDefindedListenerImpl is abstract(); cannot be instantiated. What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `mCallback` is defined but not initialized. You have to initialize it before you can use it.

Comment: how interface initialize even i want to add value in it .

Answer (score 1):

You should add a public method to the FragmentDetails class.

```
public setOnDetailsDefinedListener(OnDetailsDefinedListener listener) {
    mCallback = listener;
}
```

And just implement it in the caller class. just like how you do when add button listener.

```
mFragmentDetails.setOnDetailsDefinedListener(new OnDetailsDefinedListener() {
// You code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use onAttach(Activity activity) fragments method

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if(activity instanceof onSomeListener){
        mListener=(onSomeListener) activity;
    }
}
```